# What default shell to use for an SSH user limited to a single command

Tags: shell, ssh, account-restrictions

When limiting a user to a single command via `ssh`, what default shell should be used for the user? This is a follow up to [how can shellshock be exploited over SSH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157477/how-can-shellshock-be-exploited-over-ssh) I have a machine that is running an ssh server and has a dummy user. I have limited this dummy user to running a single command over ssh by specifying a `command` option in the `authorized_keys` file. I have been using `bash` as the default shell of the dummy user, but since the shellshock bug, I have been thinking maybe there is a more secure shell. The dummy user is only allowed to run an `rsync` command so I would image it would run on most shells. Specifically, the command that the user is allowed to run is:

```
rsync --server --sender -lHogDtpre.iLs . //home/dummyuser/data/"
```

I am not the administrator of the server, although I can ask for some easy changes, so setting up something like a chroot jail in the `/etc/sshd/sshd_config` file is not possible. Ideally, I would be able to limit the command by logging in as the dummy user with an unrestricted key.

Comment: Do you want to let him rsync with any arguments (in which case that would be equivalent to give him full shell access) or just a fixed set of arguments? What do you want to achieve in the end?

Comment: Beware that bash reads the .bashrc and /etc/bash.bashrc over ssh when invoked as "sh", and parses its code differently based on the locale. If using bash, you should call it as sh and probably remove the AcceptEnvs from sshd_config. Your best bet would be "dash" here if available, that has none of those misfeatures (and is minimalist and maintained by a kernel cryptographer). Be sure to disable tty allocation, forwarding, etc as well

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I added the command I want to limit the user to. I want the user to be able to be able to sync data from a single directory on the server.

Comment: You can also only give him chrooted sftp access to that area, and let him do the rsync over sshfs on the client. You might be trying to safeguard against a buggy shell and overlook that rsync could have many more issues and/or vulnerabilities. (in the generally case, my advice to use dash to interpret the forced command still stands).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas added that I cannot easily make system wide changes or changes to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, which I think is required to setup a chroot jail. I was kindda hoping that `rsync` would be fairly secure.

Answer (score 1):

You can write that shell:

```
cat >/tmp/rsyncshell.c <<EOF
#include <unistd.h>
char *argv[] = (char *[]) {
        "/usr/bin/rsync", "--server", "--sender", 
        "-lHogDtpre.iLs", ".", "//home/dummyuser/data/" };
int main () { execv(argv[0], argv); }
EOF
```

Compile the new shell:

```
gcc -o /bin/rsyncshell /tmp/rsyncshell.c
```

then set the dummyuser interpreter to `/bin/rsyncshell`